# How to cast signed to unsigned int for 32-bit in php

Tags: php

I have tried to cast signed int to unsigned int for 32-bit in php. but i could not able to get the absolute value for the unsigned int.

example:

```
 $value = 65547;
  if (PHP_INT_SIZE == 8)
   {
    if ($value>0x7FFFFFFF)
    {
      $value-=0x100000000;
    }
   }
```

Is any other possibilities to cast signed integer value to unsigned integer value?

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand the question. But there are no unsigned integers in PHP. PHP would automatically use `float`s before it overflows. And your example value of `65547` (2^16 + 1) is way below what a 32-bit signed integer can store (2^31 / 0x7FFFFFFF).

Comment: PHP does not support unsigned types. If the value is an integral value **and** it can be stored as integer then it is stored as integer. Otherwise it is stored as float and some of its least significant digits might be lost.

Answer (score 2):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.gmp-abs.php

For php7 you will need the php7.0-gmp package

For php5 you will need the php5-gmp package

```
var_dump((int) gmp_abs("0x7FFFFFFF"));
```

... returns

```
int(2147483647)
```

Comment: This is not actually demonstrating a cast to an unsigned int, in the sense that `0x7FFFFFFF` is still a safe signed value. We need to see what happens when the most significant digit becomes higher then 7. E.g. `0xFFFFFFFF`.